# Accessing subviews from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a collection view with cells that are populated based on an array. Each cell has a UIImageView and an UILabel. I want to be able to update the text within the UILabel each time the Cell View itself is tapped. I have the tapping gesture working fine and i can print out the sender information and access the sender view and even get the restoration identifier but I can't seem to access the 'myImage' or 'myLabel' sub views within that cell which is being tapped.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CardCell

    cell.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap)))

    let railroadName = railroadNames[indexPath.item]
    cell.myImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName:railroadName)
    cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.restorationIdentifier = railroadName

    cell.myLabel.isHidden = true
    cell.myLabel.text = "2"
    cell.myLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.52, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    cell.myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    cell.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}

@objc func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //print(sender)
    //print(sender.view?.restorationIdentifier)
}
```

Can't access subviews. Want to take the current text from 'myLabel' and increase the count by 1 each tap.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. First, you will add new gesture recognizers every time a cell is dequeued - only do this once per cell, or even better, only once for the collection view. Second, you seem to store your data in the UI objects, do this in the model instead.

Comment: @Gereon I know my code is not the best I am still learning, so I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to get label text of cell. but i insist you to manage this in railroadNames array. so, you can save label text in array object's field and can get that field value using indexpath using below code and perform operation on based of your requirement. and then you can reload that particular cell to show effect on tableview.

Also, you should use `didSelectItemAt` method to get select cell event. if not necessary reason to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
@objc func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    //Get Collection view cell indexpath on based of location of tap gesture
    let cellPosition = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)
    guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: cellPosition) else{
        print("Indexpath not found")
        return
    }

    //Get Ceollection view cell
    guard let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CellMainCategoryList else{
        print("Could't found cell")
        return
    }

    //Get String of label of collection view cell
    let strMyLable = cell. myLabel.text
    //you can process addition on based of your requirement here by getting Int from above string.
}
```

instead of above, you can manage it like below code also:

```
@objc func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let cellPosition = sender.location(in: self.collectionViewCategaries)
    guard let indexPath = self.collectionViewCategaries.indexPathForItem(at: cellPosition) else{
        print("Indexpath not found")
        return
    }
    let railroadName = railroadNames[indexPath.item]
    let myLableText = railroadName.myLabelValue
    //update value
    railroadName.myLabelValue = "2"

    self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What then when user scrolls scroll view (table view)? Data won't stay since cells are reusable. You should change data source array.

Comment: yes, i have mentioned same in answer to maintain this in array instead of directly accessing cell.

Comment: *Want to take the current text from 'myLabel' and increase the count by 1 each tap.* I have to say that is question is unclear, but from this sentence I assume that he needs to change data source array which you don't do in your answer.

Comment: okay, i have updated my answer. please let me know if still it can be improved. thanks.